# highchart remove first point

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am adding points in column chart every 1 sec. I have use addPoint function to adding point in series.
But I would like to delete the first point when count of point > 5.
Please see the code below:

```
  setInterval(() => {
          let data = self.loadData();
          let seriesData = this.userOptions.series[0].data;
          let newDataRejected = seriesData;
          if (seriesData.length > 5) {
            self.chart.series[0].data[0].remove();#ERROR
          }
          data.subscribe(el => {           
            this.series[0].addPoint([el.x, el.rejected]);              
          })
        }, 1000);
```

But in LINE #ERROR I get error `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.
How can I add and remove Points in column chats?

Comment: If your overall goal is to have x points in the graph at all times, you are better of using shift in your [addPoint function](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint). You would set `if(length < 5) {addPoint(..,true, false)} else {addPoint(...,true,true)}`. Would look like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/9pa5gjqw/26/

Comment: Either `self.chart.series` or `self.chart.series[0].data` is undefined. You should check `self.chart` and its properties.

Comment: Thanks @ewolden. It is works!!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of manually removing the first point, a better solution is to use the shift property of the [`addPoint`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint) function.

You would then need to do:

```
setInterval(() => {
  let data = self.loadData();
  let seriesData = this.userOptions.series[0].data;
  let newDataRejected = seriesData;
  if (seriesData.length > 5) {
    data.subscribe(el => {           
      this.series[0].addPoint([el.x, el.rejected], true, true);              
    })
  } else {
    data.subscribe(el => {           
      this.series[0].addPoint([el.x, el.rejected], true, false);              
    })
  }

}, 1000);
```

**Working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/1c5hkj8g/